# An Oracle Select with time

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm converting a mysql system to use oracle, but I'm having problems with this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM recent_activity 
 WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), lastactivity )) < 5
```

I know that `NOW()` uses `systimestamp` and `lastactivity` is a timestamp.
I'm trying to check activities in the last 5 seconds.

Do you know how I can write this in Oracle?

Comment: Right now I have :  SELECT * FROM recent_activity WHERE EXTRACT (DAY FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity))*24*60*60+EXTRACT (HOUR   FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity))*60*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity))*60+ EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity)) DELTA < 5    But it still doesnt work

Comment: A second can be represented as 1/24/60/60, so try something like "where (systimestamp-lastactivity) < 5/24/60/60"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from recent_activity where systimestamp-lastactivity < interval '5' second;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I think I got this working:

```
 SELECT * FROM recent_activity WHERE EXTRACT (DAY FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity))*24*60*60+EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity))*60*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity))*60+ EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (systimestamp-lastactivity)) < 5
```

Comment: erk! wouldn't it be simpler to...`SELECT * FROM recent_activity WHERE SYSDATE-5/86400 < lastactivity` (which also allows you to use indexes)

Answer (score 0):

create table blah (blah1 timestamp, blah2 timestamp);

insert into blah values (systimestamp, systimestamp - .00005);

select * from blah;

```
Blah1                                   Blah2
01/OCT/13 02:17:41.300000000 PM         01/OCT/13 02:17:37.000000000 PM
```

so in your case you should be simply able to do

```
select * 
from recent_activity
where lastactivity > (NOW() - .00005)
```

This actually gives you the last 4.3 seconds as it rounds but probably close enough for most solutions or make it .00006 to get 5.some seconds if it is better to go over.